# C++ - How to display an icon in a dialog in gtkmm

Tags: c++, dialog, icons, gtkmm

I have several Dialog in my program that tells the users various things, from errors, to confirmation.

The sample in the documentation tells me to use this to have an icon set depending on the dialog (warning, information, question mark...):

```
Gtk::MessageDialog dialog(*this, "This is a QUESTION MessageDialog",
    false /* use_markup */, Gtk::MESSAGE_QUESTION,
    Gtk::BUTTONS_OK_CANCEL);
```

However, I do not get any icon in the dialog, I am only able to change the icon in the top bar, using this :

```
Gtk::MessageDialog dialog(*this,~     
    "Please select something first.",
    false,                        
    Gtk::MESSAGE_ERROR,           
    Gtk::BUTTONS_OK);             
dialog.set_icon_name("dialog-error"); 
dialog.run();
```

I get no error, no warning, this compile and execute just fine, but the resulting message box doesn't have any icon in it. How can I get an icon to display properly INSIDE my dialog box ? I also tried the other MESSAGE_* available, without success.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Gtk3 documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDialog.html) one should use GtkDialog to create dialogs with images.

You may use `set_image` but it is deprecated since 3.12.

More concrete:

> **void Gtk::MessageDialog::set_image(Widget& image)**
>
> Sets the dialog’s image to image.
>
> Since gtkmm 2.10:
>       Deprecated: 3.12: Use Gtk::Dialog to create dialogs with images
>
> Deprecated:
>       Use Dialog to create dialogs with images.
>
> Parameters
>       image The image.